# EntityManager from persistence Context not working with Spring Async Method

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

In my regular SpringBoot application , I need to capture the user activity asynchronously. My DB tables are related badly that it is not possible to leverage SPring data JPA. Hence I am using EntityManager from persistence context to execute the DB operation. However the inserts in the child table is not being done.
The below code is being invoked from a method annotated with @Async
Here is the code :
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

```
private Query query;

@Override
@Transactional
public void saveUserClicks(Pojo pojo)
        throws DataIntegrityViolationException {

    
    StringBuilder q1 = new StringBuilder(
            "query1");
    StringBuilder q2 = new StringBuilder(
            "query2");

    Query q1NativeQuery = getNativeQuery(entityManager.createNativeQuery(q1.toString()));
    q1NativeQuery.setParameter(1, param1);
    q1NativeQuery.setParameter(2, param2);
    
    int executed = q1NativeQuery.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Value of executed:" + executed);

    Set<ChildPOJO> set = obj1.getSet();
    if (null != set) {
        for (ChildPOJO child : set) {
                q1NativeQuery = getNativeQuery(entityManager.createNamedQuery(q2.toString()));
                q1NativeQuery.setParameter(1, param1);
                q1NativeQuery.setParameter(2, param2);
                executed = q1NativeQuery.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Value of executed :" + executed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. I changed the code from NamedQuery to native Query and it worked.

```
From 

q1NativeQuery = getNativeQuery(entityManager.createNamedQuery(q2.toString()));

To 

q1NativeQuery = getNativeQuery(entityManager.createNativeQuery(q2.toString()));
```

I hope it helps someone.